# Create an universal Xamarin project for iOS, android and windows phone

Tags: xamarin

I have tried on a Mac OS X computer and on a Windows 10 PC. I want to create a mobile application with Xamarin. I want to run this application on both iOS, Android and Windows Phone devices.

When i am creating a new solution, i can choose a multiplateform Application Project, but it creates sub projects for each architecture. I want a single project common for the 3 architecture. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: You will at minimum have a project for each platform, which contains the necessary bootstrap logic for the App, and a single shared/PCL project that contains the shared code for the App.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Cross Platform project you have to (in Xamarin Studio. If you want UWP, you have to use Visual Studio)

1. File -> New Solution
2. App -> Forms App -> Next
3. App name ->
   Target platforms -> Select PCL or Shared Project (I prefer PCL) ->
   Next
4. Location -> Create

at the end you should have a PCL project and X Platform Specific Projects

Comment: On mac os x, i only have android and iOS checkboxes and sub projects, but an official xamarin tutorial says it will work on windows phone. Do you confirm ?

Comment: [This table](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Development_Environments) shows which platforms can be built with different development tool & operating system combinations.

Comment: @Bob5421 on Mac you can use XF for Android and iOS. on Windows (Visual Studio) you can use XF for Android, UWP and iOS (to build a iOS app you must have a mac connected to your windows PC)

Comment: If i develop on my Mac, and if i only work with main project files (i mean i do not look at iOS subproject and Android subproject), this mean i will work with XF, does it ? And in this case, if i want a windows phone app, i just have to open the same project on a windows computer without changing anything? Will it work ? Thanks

Comment: @Bob5421 Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to easily create native user interface layouts that can be shared across Android, iOS, and Windows Phone. If you crate your XF project on a MAC, you will not have UWP project so, if you want to open the same project on a Windows PC, you'll have to add manually the UWP project. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a full multi-platform app (iOS, Android, Windows phone, MacOS, Windows) you need to use visual studio on Windows. Using Xamarin Studio on the Mac will only allow Mac and Android projects. Still you want to create a Xamarin Forms App, Portable application.

Answer (score 0):

Only  Visual Studio you can create projects for platforms IOS, Android e UWP, for it you need connect your Mac the network (Xamarin Mac Agent) for build applications for IOS.

On IOS you only create projects on XamarinStudio or Visual Studio For Mac for platform Android and IOS.